# Wi-Fi Direct doesn't connect devices on WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to connect two devices by Wi-Fi Direct but these are not connected. I tested both in my application and in [Proximity Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Proximity-Sample-88129731), the same error occurs:

- **"Error this operation returned because the timeout period expired. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070584)"** - Beside whom requested the connection
- **"A device attached to the system is not Functioning. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007001F)"** - the side of whoever accepts the connection.

This happens during the call:

```
StreamSocket socket = await PeerFinder.ConnectAsync(peer);
```

Sometimes the devices are connected, but in most cases doesn't connect.

Someone is having the same problem?
Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: Have the same problem in Windows 10 tablets (App designed for Win 8.1). Curious to find what's the reason behind this..

Comment: Same problem here as well (W10M build 14393.x), posted on the msdn forum as well: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/767cdb62-a991-4b6a-8d23-1ba4fa4067e5/uwp-winrt-peerfinderconnectasync-method-doesnt-work-cant-create-a-socket-connection?forum=wpdevelop